# Django can't load static files

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to load static files in my django project to the html template. My project structure as follow:

```
base
    settings
        __init__.py
        defaults.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
data
web
    migrations
    static
        css
        fonts
        img
        js
    templates
        base
            base.html
        pages
            blank.html
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

I defined the following in my defaults.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = 'web/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
]
```

my views.py in the "web" app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def blank_page(request):

    return render(request, 'pages/blank.html')
```

urls.py in "web" app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url  

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.blank_page, name='index'),
]
```

urls.py in "base" app:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
import sys

admin.site.site_header = os.environ.get('ADMIN_SITE_HEADER') or 'Django administration'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('web.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG or 'test' in sys.argv:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

When i use href in my html template in base.html when calling to the root url from localhost i can't get the static file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

i tried to change my STATIC_URL to /static/ or web/static/ and i still can't get the statics files in my static folder.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: The `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting is empty and there is no `STATIC_ROOT` setting, so Django doesn't know where to look for the static files on the disk.

Comment: i tried STATICFILES_DIRS = [ '/web/static/'] and got this error "No such file or directory: '/web/static'"

Comment: Try `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web/static')`

Comment: oh ok it worked now thank :). i don't know i have to use os path because the docs just use the basic relative path